# How to set expiration time for individual records in memcache in zend framework 2 without affecting the ttl

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, memcached

I have a requirement where I need to set expiration time for a value in zend framework2 for 30 minutes i.e. 1800 seconds but the default ttl is 10 minutes i.e. 600 seconds.

The idea is for this individual record the expiration time will be different than the default ttl and this should not affect expiration time for previous and consequent records set in the memcache.

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirements, you have to define unique keys for each record if you want to set different TTL times

```
$memcache->set('recordKeyOne', $youRecordOne, false, 1800)
$memcache->set('recordKeyTwo', $youRecordTwo, false, 300)
```

This way both the objects will expire based on the expiration set while creating the object.

Comment: Dear Harshal,I am setting different memcache keys but the problem is I want to differ their expiration time in cache.

Comment: protected function internalSetItem(& $normalizedKey, & $value) {
        $memc = $this->getMemcacheResource();
        $expiration = $this->getExpiryTimeForItem() == 0 ? $this->expirationTime() : $this->getExpiryTimeForItem();
        $flag = $this->getWriteFlag($value);

        if (!$memc->set($this->namespacePrefix . $normalizedKey, $value, $flag, $expiration)) {
            throw new Exception\RuntimeException('Memcache set value failed');
        }

        return true;
    }

Comment: public function getExpiryTimeForItem() {
        return $this->expiryTimeForItem;
    }
    public function setExpiryTimeForItem($expiryTimeForItem) {
        $this->expiryTimeForItem = $expiryTimeForItem;
    }

Comment: @user1936330 you can edit your question, that will make it more readable and informative

Comment: I know but I don't want to.